# Camera to follow player but 'snap' to screen boarders

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a camera class for a Jumping Platformer Example. [Link Here](http://gamepopperdev.wordpress.com/games/2012-2/jumping-platformer-example/)

I just don't understand how I can make the camera follow the player 'ball'. I know the tiles are always on screen at all times, but I want to extend the map X,Y and use a camera to follow the player as you navigate the world.

If someone could check the tutorial out, and explain to me how to add a camera class, I would be very thank full. (new to XNA)

Comment: You need to make a start or show some code. You can't expect people to watch a video to help you out..

Comment: I don't know where to start, or what to show you. There isn't that much code. There is a download link, if you would be so kind to download the example and take a look..?

Comment: I added an answer that works fine and is small, but the example you pointed out has a source code that you can look at. It's probably filled with more than what you're asking for but perhaps next time you can actually download it and look and try for yourself and post a question when you have tried something but doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. It might be done easier, but this is the general idea:

This is a simple method for "X" coordinate. Can later be duplicated for a Y coordinate also, but, it could be done simpler. But this is to show the whole process. You could just use Math.Max(Math.Min()) and calculate these values in a shorter form, but this works.

You can see the whole source code here:
http://pastebin.com/G969mz0f

Will require a Texture file "player" and you have to remove the "Program.cs" because I put it all in one file.

```
public void Move(float x, float y, Camera2D Camera)
{

    Position.X += x;

    if ((Position.X < Camera.Min.X))
       Position.X = Camera.Min.X;

    if ((Position.X + Width) > Camera.Max.X)
       Position.X = Camera.Max.X - Width;

    float centerX = Position.X + (Width / 2);

    if (centerX > (Camera.Min.X + (ScreenDimension.X / 2)))
    {
        if (centerX < (Camera.Max.X - (ScreenDimension.X / 2)))
        {
            Camera.Move(-x, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Camera.SetPosition(-(Camera.Max.X - ScreenDimension.X), Camera.Position.Y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Camera.SetPosition(Camera.Min.X, Camera.Position.Y);
    }

    // Removed Y because of code length

}
```

Comment: Couldn't that be made much more concise with MathHelper.Clamp()?

Comment: Sure this could done easier, but understanding how it works is also good. How you in any math calculate the limits. This is also a solution (for X coordinate of Camera): position.X = (MathHelper.Clamp(x - (ScreenDimensions.X / 2f), Min.X, Max.X - ScreenDimensions.X)); and then you instead use -Position.X in the Transformation Matrix. Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0); I called the method "CenterTo" and if the camera can't center to an object it instead will use it's boundaries.